# xCode Creating UIImagePickerController and Referencing It

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

for my app I want to create a custom camera overlay and create a UIImagePickerController to start recording video. (below)

```
- (IBAction)RecordVideo:(UIButton *)sender {

    //initialise camera view
    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    cameraUI.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    cameraUI.showsCameraControls = NO;
    cameraUI.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    cameraUI.toolbarHidden = YES;

    OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc]
                        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20,20)];

    cameraUI.cameraOverlayView = overlay;

    [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

as part of the `cameraOverlayView` I've instantiated a UIButton:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        //clear the background color of the overlay
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        ... some overlay UI stuff


        UIButton *captureBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        UIImage *captureBtnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"captureBtn.png"];
        [captureBtn setBackgroundImage:captureBtnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        captureBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2 - 15,
                                      430,
                                      80,
                                      80);
        [self addSubview:captureBtn];
    }
    return self;
}
```

So how do I create an `IBAction` for this button which can then make the `UIImagePickerController cameraUI` start recording?

If somebody could also explain to me how the IBActions are called from specific buttons only that would also be amazing because that seems like black magic to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add target like this,

```
[captureBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(captureBtnclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and you action method shoulbe like this

```
-(void)captureBtnclick :(UIButton*)sender{

//handle your task on click here

}
```

second thing why you are adding layer on it? you can use default video recording from imagePicker by setting mediatype like

```
cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

**Update accroding to comment**

you can use on button click,

```
 [picker startVideoCapture]; //in your case cameraUI i think
```

**Update 2** :

in your .h file,

```
@property UIImagePickerController *cameraUI;
```

then in your method `RecordVideo` use like,

```
self.cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

 //etc.....
```

By this way you can use `camaraUI` in whole class by `self`

hope this will help :)

Comment: That's very helpful thank you! Do you have any ideas as to how I should go about making it start the UIImagePickerController recording though?

Comment: Why are you adding overlayview?

Comment: I need to add a custom overlay as part of the design spec. I need to have only two buttons as well (one to record and one to accept the recording) I understand this is the way to do it?

Comment: can't you use default record button which comes when open uiimagepickercontroller with mediatype movie?

Comment: I don't think so. It has to be a custom image and then it has to record for a limited amount of time (5 seconds).

Comment: thank you again, I tried this but it tells me that cameraUI is an undeclared identifier (i presume because it's created in the context of another method)?

Comment: Definitely  you should take as property or public. second thing don't make new class for overlay view. just create this view programmatically when needed and add neccessary button created programatically on it and add this view on camaraUI. By this way your button action methods and `camaraUI` property or instance variable will be cover in one class so you can easily call or manipulate anything from it

Comment: Updated my answer check it.